# getting a Webkit executeSql transaction to return a value

Tags: javascript, sqlite, webkit

How can I get the following JavaScript to return `row` so I can access it outside the transaction? All of Apple's example code seems to have HTML written to the browser within the transaction instead of ever passing data back to a calling function.

Along the lines of:

```
function getData() {
  db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql("SELECT id FROM table LIMIT 1", [], function(tx, result) {
      row = result.rows.item(0);
    }, function(tx, error) {
    });
  });

  return row;
}
```

Is this even possible? Can the Webkit storage API be set to synchronous instead of asynchronous execution?

Comment: Are you using a JavaScript library that's openly available?

Where's the example?

Comment: It's not a library, it's built into Webkit. See http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/UsingtheJavascriptDatabase/chapter_5_section_5.html for details.

Comment: This question helped me clarify the executeSql method's available parameters^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want to create a closure here as values are being garbage collected/moved away from the scope chain before you can access them. Pass `row` to a closure for access later or to some other function that can handle the value while it's still in scope.

More info: [Working With Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Closures)

Comment: i would be very interested in seeing how you would do that (i mean via a closure). I tryed many times but nothing worked.

Answer (score 5):

I realise this is a very old question but I found it when searching for how to deal with JavaScript asynchronous SQLite calls. And the question is the same as mine and I've found a better answer (Expands on the selected answer, using closures)

my version of your getData function is as follows:

```
function get_option (option, get_option_callback){
    if (db === null){
       open_database();
    }
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql("SELECT rowid,* FROM app_settings WHERE option = ? ", [option],            
        function(tx, result){
            item = result.rows.item(0);
            get_option_callback(item.value);
            return;
         }
       }, sql_err);
   });
}
```

Then to call the method I would use:

```
get_option("option name", function(val){
 // set the html element value here with val
 // or do whatever
 $('input[name="some_input"]').val(val);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an example of this and other SQL transactions at: http://wecreategames.com/blog/?p=219

You have to do the WebKit executeSql calls in an asynchronous style.  To get around this, you should have your:

```
function(tx, error) {
}
```

execute something to update your data. Something like:

```
function(tx, results) {
   console.log("Results returned: "+results.rows.length);
   for (var i=0; i<results.rows.length; i++) {
      var row = results.rows.item(i);
      document.getElementById('latestUpdated').innerHTML = row;
   } 
}
```

Notice that the second variable into the function isn't an error, it's the results.

I put in a for loop to show that there could be multiple results returned (probably not with that SQL statement, though) -- so hopefully you see the utility of it.