# How to return the selected values from SQLite statement?

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova

I am developing an application for iPhone but I write JavaScript. I store some information (the id and the name of an item) in the local database and now I need to get that information back so that I can use it. Unfortunately, the database returns to me undefined value but if I alert the value before the return statement, I get it correctly. My code is below:

```
function DB() {
    myDatabase.transaction(function (transaction) {
        transaction.executeSql("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id = ?", [idNum],

            function (transaction, resultSet) {
                var i = 0;
                var currentRow = resultSet.rows.item(i);
                return currentRow.name;
            },

            function (transaction, error) {
                alert('error:' + error.message);
            }
        );
    })
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [getting a Webkit executeSql transaction to return a value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740523/getting-a-webkit-executesql-transaction-to-return-a-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transaction method you are using does not return a value. Instead it passes it to a result function. Returning a result from the result function does nothing. You have to use the result of the query within the result function.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the data is in the database?

If that is all that you need to store you may be better off using localStorage.

http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/storage.html

Comment: I am sure that I store the information in the database because (as I added in the description) if I put an alert above the return statement, I get the correct value of the item...